# socket.io - trigger emit from server-side?

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

How can I trigger an emit from the server-side with socketIO ? 
I have a `socket.on('My_Event')` on my nodejs server and I wish to trigger that event from some place else on my server with `.emit('My_Event')`.
My goal here is to broadcast to the client-side some notification datas.

**server side - app.js**

```
var app = express(),
    server = http.createServer(app),
    io = require('socket.io')(server);

io.on('connection', function(socket){
    socket.on('My_Event', function(data){
        socket.volatile.emit('event', data);
    });
});

server.listen(config.listenPort, '0.0.0.0', 511, function() {
    // config.listenPort is already defined
    console.log('node Server - listening on port: ' + config.listenPort);
});
```

**export** - the module from which I'd like to trigger the event

```
var io = require('socket.io')();

exports.addStrategy = function(app) {

  var fn = {

    doSomething : function(req, res, next) {

      // HERE I wish to trigger my socket event
      // io.emit('MY_EVENT', {}); ????

      res.status(200).json(done());
  };
  return fn;
};
```

so far I can't get it to work. is it how I should do it ?

Answer (score 1):

One option is to create a single global instance of Socket.IO that could eventually be shared across multiple modules/applications.

```
global.socket = require('socket.io').listen(app);
```

Happy Helping!

Comment: ok. I'll try that. not really a fan of global instances though